# Using Tensorflow's batched matrix multiplication

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

```
Tensor A is [M X 2N X N]
Tensor B is [M X N]
```

I need to multiply the two tensors to get:

```
Tensor C [M X 2N X N].
```

Here is an example:

```
M= 2, N = 2

A: [[[1,2]
     [1,2]
     [1,2]
     [1,2] ]

    [[2,2]
     [2,2]
     [2,2]
     [2,2] ]]

 B = [[3,3]
      [2,2]]

 C: [[[3,6]
      [3,6]
      [3,6]
      [3,6] ]

      [[4,4]
       [4,4]
       [4,4]
       [4,4] ]]
```

Not sure how to achieve this. Along with the solution, can someone please explain how broadcasting exactly works in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want elementwise multiplication where tensor B is repeated 2N times in that dimension. I'd do the broadcast manually using tf.concat(2, [tf.reshape(b, [m, 1, n]) for _ in xrange(2*n)]).